# Como gerar timestamp em milissegundos em PHP?

Tags: php

A função `time()` do PHP gera um timestamp UNIX em segundos, exemplo:

```
echo time() // 1420996448
```

Mas eu gostaria de gerar um timestamp Unix também com os milissegundos, como eu posso fazer isto?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilizando a função [`microtime()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.microtime.php) combinada com [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.round.php) você consegue retornar um timestamp em milissegundos, exemplo:

```
round(microtime(true) * 1000);
```

Como a função `microtime()` por padrão retorna uma `string` no *peculiar* formato `"ms seg"`, nós podemos passar o parametro `true` para ela, que faz com que o valor retornado seja um `float` no formato: `seg.ms`.

Com o `float`, você pode fazer um simples cálculo multiplicando-o por mil (`1000`) e arredondando o resultado final de forma a sempre retornar um timestamp em formato `int`.

Exemplo da função acima desmembrada para melhor entendimento:

```
microtime();                   // 0.68353600 1420997025
microtime(true);               // 1420997065.6835
microtime(true) * 1000;        // 14209970656835.3
round(microtime(true) * 1000); // 14209970656835
```